# C programming about "double" multiplication

Tags: c

I'm currently learning the C language and I'm having trouble in the `double` multiplication topic.

I need to to print the original value and then the `2*value` of the `double`.

```
double num = 34.39;
printf("Original value = %d,   2x original value = %d", num, num*2);
```

How do I make it so that the 2x value will be really 2x the original value?

Comment: `printf("Original value = %g, 2x original value = %g", num, num*2); "`?

Comment: You should take the habit of compiling with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and you should *use the debugger* (`gdb`)

Comment: Please read the documentation of every function that you are using. See [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: this parameter: num*2 should be num*2.0

Comment: these format specifiers:  %d, are for integers.  a far better format specifier would be "%lf"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your multiplication is not the problem.

Your `printf` format string is. `%d` is not for floating-point values, but for integers, so you're seeing nonsense resulting from your broken contract with the compiler.

```
double num = 34.39;
printf("Original value = %lf,   2x original value = %lf", num, num*2);
```

Comment: Why do you refer to this as "contract with the compiler"? The compiler merely expands floating-point arguments to 8 bytes (if needed, which is not the case here anyway) before calling `printf`. Wouldn't it be more accurate to call it "contract with `printf`"?

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes; more generally I meant "contract with the implementation of C", of which `printf` is a part.

Answer (score 4):

%d - for int
You must use the "%f" for printf

Comment: Yeap that's it!
Thx for help